# UWP: Manipulation in a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, xaml, scroll, uwp, swipe

I am using a translateX manipulation in my app. but when I want to use it in a scrollviewer, The scrollviewer stops working and doesn't scroll(I need the vertical rail).
What to do to fix it.
MyXAML code:

```
<ScrollViewer>    
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid"  Background="{ThemeResource AppBackgroundColor}"
         ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationDelta="MainGrid_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationCompleted="MainGrid_ManipulationCompleted"
         ManipulationStarted="MainGrid_ManipulationStarted" 

         >
            <ContentControl  Content="{x:Bind TheGrid,Mode=OneWay}"/>

            <Grid.RenderTransform >

                <TranslateTransform  x:Name="myScaleTransform" />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And my C# codebehind:

```
#region Manipulations
        private void MainGrid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myScaleTransform.X >= 60 && e.Delta.Translation.X > 1)
            {
                myScaleTransform.X = 60;
                return;
            }
            if (myScaleTransform.X <= -180 && e.Delta.Translation.X < 1)
            {
                myScaleTransform.X = -180;
                return;
            }
            myScaleTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
            lastPostition.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;

        }

        private void MainGrid_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myScaleTransform.X <= -170 ) return;
            urStoryboard.Begin();

        }

        private void MainGrid_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            startpoint = e.Position;
            lastPostition = e.Position;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: You can't... at least not that I'm aware of. Once you change the value of `ManipulationMode` to anything other than `System`, you turn off direct manipulation on the `ScrollViewer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FIXED it.
My code:

```
ManipulationMode="TranslateX,System"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great for me after messing around with many different attempts at getting this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no good solution if the `ScrollViewer` needs both scrolling and gestures. If you want to handle user's gestures you have to disable `DirectManipulation` and this disables scrolling as well. 
There's an article talk about this problem, you should read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/02/15/where-did-all-my-gestures-go/) to understand more.